# How do I replace this text with quotation marks?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = '';
```

in `/var/lib/roundcube/config/main.inc.php`

with

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'localhost';
```

I've tried:

```
sed -i "s/$rcmail_config['default_host'] = '';/$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'localhost';/g" /var/lib/roundcube/config/main.inc.php
```

and

```
sed -i s/$rcmail_config['default_host'] = '';/$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'localhost';/g /var/lib/roundcube/config/main.inc.php
```

But it does not work.

What could I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` and `[` symbols and also you don't need to repeat the same string in the replacement part. Instead of this, you may use capturing groups.

```
sed -i "s/\(\$rcmail_config\['default_host'\] = \)'';/\1'localhost';/g" file
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Question, why do the `$` and `[` symbols need to be escaped?

Comment: @narzero in regex `$` means the end of the string and `[` is considered as the start of a character class. You need to escape the both, so that it matches a literal `$`,`[` symbols.